Flutter: Unable to Replace Existing Database with Imported File from Local Storage (PathNotFoundException)
I'm working on a Flutter app where I need to replace an existing SQLite database file (app_name.db) with a file selected from the user's local storage on their device. I successfully implemented a method to export the database (I've tested the exported file), but I'm running into issues when trying to import and replace the existing database file.
Export Method:
The following method works perfectly to export the database:
Future<void> exportDatabase() async {
    try {
        // Get the directory where the databases are stored on Android
        String databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();

        // Full path to the existing database file
        String originalPath = join(databasesPath, 'app_name.db');

        // Get the target directory where you want to copy the file (typically app's documents directory)
        Directory targetDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

        // Full path to the new file with the .appname extension
        String newPath = join(targetDir.path, 'data.appname');

        // Copy the original database file to the new location with the new extension
        File originalFile = File(originalPath);

        // Check if the file exists before attempting to copy
        if (await originalFile.exists()) {
            File newFile = await originalFile.copy(newPath);

            await Share.shareXFiles([XFile(newFile.path)]);

            // Optionally, delete the copied file after sharing
            await newFile.delete();

            log('Database exported and deleted successfully.', name: "SettingsRepository.exportDatabase");
        } else {
            log('Original database file does not exist.', name: "SettingsRepository.exportDatabase");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        log("Error during export", name: "SettingsRepository.exportDatabase", error: e);
    }
}

Import Method:
However, when I try to import the database using the following code, I encounter issues:
Future<void> importDatabase(VoidCallback onFileWrongExtension) async {
    try {
        // Pick the file from the device storage
        FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
            type: FileType.any, // Allow picking any file type
        );

        if (result != null && result.files.single.path != null) {
            // Get the path of the selected file
            String importedFilePath = result.files.single.path!;

            // Check if the selected file has the correct .appname extension
            if (importedFilePath.endsWith('.appname')) {
                // Get the directory where the application stores files
                Directory appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                String newPath = join(appDir.path, 'app_name.db');

                // Copy and rename the imported file
                File importedFile = File(importedFilePath);
                File newFile = await importedFile.copy(newPath);

                // Replace the database
                await _replaceDatabase(newFile);

                log('Database imported and replaced successfully.');
            } else {
                onFileWrongExtension();
                log('Selected file is not a .appname file.');
            }
        } else {
            log('File picking canceled or failed.');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        log("Error during import", error: e);
    }
}

The Problem:
Despite ensuring that the directory exists and attempting both rename and copy operations, I consistently receive the following error when trying to replace the database file:
Exception: Error replacing the database: PathNotFoundException: Cannot copy file to
'/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1234567-123A-4E6D-9991-D5FEA2F7415D/Documents/app_name.db', 
  path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1234567-123A-4E6D-9991-D5FEA2F7415D/Documents/app_name.db' 
  (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Replace Database Method:
Here’s the _replaceDatabase function that handles the replacement:
Future<void> _replaceDatabase(File newFile) async {
    try {
        // Get the application directory where the database is stored
        Directory appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String dbPath = join(appDir.path, 'app_name.db');

        // Ensure the directory exists
        if (!(await appDir.exists())) {
            await appDir.create(recursive: true);
        }

        // Close the database connection
        await DatabaseDAO.getInstance().closeDB();

        // Check if the database file already exists and delete if so
        File dbFile = File(dbPath);
        if (await dbFile.exists()) {
            await dbFile.delete();
        }

        // Attempt to rename the file (faster if on the same filesystem)
        try {
            await newFile.rename(dbPath);
        } catch (e) {
            // If renaming fails, try copying instead (handles cross-filesystem)
            await newFile.copy(dbPath);
            await newFile.delete();
        }

        // Reopen the database connection
        await DatabaseDAO.getInstance().initDatabase();

        log('Database replaced and reinitialized successfully.');
    } catch (e) {
        log("Error replacing the database", error: e);
        throw Exception("Error replacing the database: $e");
    }
}

Environment:

Flutter Version: 3.24.0
sqflite Package Version: ^2.3.3+1
Device: iOS and Android
FilePicker Package: ^8.0.7

Question:
Why am I encountering this PathNotFoundException, and how can I successfully replace the existing SQLite database file with the selected file from local storage?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I've found a working solution:
Importing the Database
The following method allows you to pick a file from the user's device and import it as the new database:
Future<void> importDatabase(VoidCallback onFileWrongExtension) async {
    try {
        // Pick the file from the device storage
        FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
            type: FileType.any, // Allow picking any file type
        );

        if (result != null && result.files.single.path != null) {
            // Get the path of the selected file
            String importedFilePath = result.files.single.path!;

            // Check if the selected file has the correct .appname extension
            if (importedFilePath.endsWith('.appname')) {
                // Get the directory where the application stores files
                Directory appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

                // Destination path for the imported file
                String newPath = join(appDir.path, 'app_name.db');

                // Copy and rename the imported file
                File importedFile = File(importedFilePath);
                File newFile = await importedFile.copy(newPath);

                // Replace the database or merge data as needed
                await _replaceDatabase(newFile);

                log('Database imported and replaced successfully.', name: "SettingsRepository.importDatabase");
            } else {
                onFileWrongExtension();
                log('Selected file is not a .appname file.', name: "SettingsRepository.importDatabase");
            }
        } else {
            log('File picking canceled or failed.', name: "SettingsRepository.importDatabase");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        log("Error during import", name: "SettingsRepository.importDatabase", error: e.toString());
    }
}


Replacing the Database
The _replaceDatabase function handles replacing the current database with the imported one:
Future<void> _replaceDatabase(File newFile) async {
    try {
        // Get the database path using the appropriate method
        String dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
        String finalDbPath = join(dbPath, 'app_name.db');

        // Ensure the database directory exists
        if (!(await Directory(dbPath).exists())) {
            await Directory(dbPath).create(recursive: true);
        }

        // Validate the imported database by checking for a known table or structure
        bool isValid = await _validateImportedDatabase(newFile.path);
        if (!isValid) {
            log('The imported database is invalid or missing expected tables/data.');
            throw Exception('Invalid database file.');
        }

        // Close the existing database connection
        await DatabaseDAO.getInstance().closeDB();

        // Check if the existing database file exists and delete it if so
        File dbFile = File(finalDbPath);
        if (await dbFile.exists()) {
            await dbFile.delete();
        }

        // Rename the new file to the final database path (preferable for performance)
        try {
            await newFile.rename(finalDbPath);
        } catch (e) {
            // If renaming fails, copy the file instead (for cross-filesystem operations)
            await newFile.copy(finalDbPath);
            await newFile.delete();
        }

        // Reopen the database connection
        await DatabaseDAO.getInstance().initDatabase();

        log('Database replaced and reinitialized successfully.');
    } catch (e) {
        log("Error replacing the database", error: e);
        throw Exception("Error replacing the database: $e");
    }
}


Validating the Imported Database
Before replacing the existing database, it’s essential to validate the structure of the imported database to ensure it has the necessary tables:
Future<bool> _validateImportedDatabase(String dbPath) async {
    Database? db;
    try {
        // Open the imported database
        db = await openDatabase(dbPath);

        // Check for a specific table that should exist
        List<Map<String, dynamic>> tables = await db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='expected_table_name'");

        // Validate if the table exists
        if (tables.isNotEmpty) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        log('Error validating imported database: $e');
    }
    return false;  // Table does not exist
}

